# Upload image and display in browser in spring webflow

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I had a requirement of getting the image from the filesystem and displaying it in browser. The code i had tried till now is shown below:

.jsp code:

```
<formspring:form enctype="multipart/form-data" modelAttribute="onlinePurchase">
   Please select a file to upload : <input type="file" name="multipartFileUpload" id="multipartFileUpload" />
   <div class="submit">
        <input type="submit" id="upload" name="_eventId_upload"
            value="Upload Image" />
        </div>
 </formspring:form>
```

controller code:

```
  public void saveImage(OnlinePurchase onlinepurchase,
        MultipartFile multipartFile) {

    try {
        onlinepurchase.setContent(multipartFile.getBytes());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    onlinepurchase.setContentSize(new Long(multipartFile.getSize())
            .intValue());
    onlinepurchase.setContentType(multipartFile.getContentType());
    onlinepurchase.setFilename(multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());

}
```

flow.xml code:

```
 <view-state id="onlinePurchaseStep1" view="onlinepurchase/onlinepurchaserequest-step-1"
    model="onlinePurchase">

    <on-render>
        <evaluate expression="oPAction.initialize" />
    </on-render>
    <transition on="submit" to="onlinePurchaseStep1" validate="false">
        <evaluate expression="oPAction.cropImage" />
    </transition>
    <transition on="upload" to="onlinePurchaseStep1" validate="false">
        <evaluate
    expression="oPAction.saveImage(onlinePurchase,requestParameters.multipartFileUpload)"
            result="" result-type="" />
    </transition>
    <transition on="success" to="onlinePurchaseStep2">
        <evaluate expression="oPAction.addMedia" />
    </transition>

    <transition on="cancel" to="login" validate="false" />
</view-state>
```

The issue is that saveImage(OnlinePurchase onlinepurchase, String multipartFile) method in action is not getting called.
Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: No Stacktrace available?

Answer (score 0):

You need a MultipartResolver :
add this line in your springs's webmvc xml configuration file.

```
   <bean id ="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/>
```

Note that the CommonsMultipartResolver uses classes from org.apache.commons.io package so you may need to add commons-io.jar in your classpath.
If your project is maven you can add the following dependency in the pom:

```
     <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId> 
        <version>a valid version</version> <!-- 2.4 worked for me -->
     </dependency>
```